# Cannot modify record in table using MVC 4 beta Yet I can add records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC framework. I am using MVC 4 beta and now I am having some trouble. I have googled alot but could not found a solution to my problem so here I am hoping that some one can help with that. My problem is I have two databases

```
   Database1 db1=new Database1();
   Database2 db2=new Database2();

   tbl1 tb1=new tbl1(); /// from db1
   tbl2 tb2=new tbl2(); // from db2
```

both tables have same properties except in db2 does not contain any relations on any property.

here is my code

```
   public bool Save(int id=0){
   tb1 = db1.tbl1.Single(tr => tr.id == id);

   tb2.a=tb1.a;
   tb2.b=tb1.b;
   tb2.c=tb1.c;
   tb2.d=tb1.d;
   tb2.e=tb1.e;

    if (db2.tbl1.SingleOrDefault(tr => tr.rid == id) == null)
            {
                db2.tbl1.AddObject(tb2); /// This works perfectly fine
            }
            else
            {

                db2.tbl1.Attach(tb2); /// This gives me an error Object Reference does not set to an instance of an object 
                db2.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(tb2, EntityState.Modified);

            }
            db2.SaveChanges();
   }
```

The funny thing is I am using same method on another controller and it is working like a charm. Any suggestions why it's happening and how to solve it will be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: it has been two days now and nobody even viewed my question, whats going on people ?

Answer (score 0):

I had googled a lot and found the solution on the MSDN. Here is how I solved the problem I just removed the line

```
    db2.tbl1.Attach(tb2);
```

And it worked like a charm.

Here is a little explanation of what is happening here, when I search the record in DB if exist or not then, if it exist then it automatically attached to the DBcontext so you just have to change the state of the DB like this

```
    db2.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(tb2, EntityState.Modified);
```

and save the record.

```
    db2.SaveChanges();
```

In case there is no record found in the database then you have to add new dbcontext to the db2 as 
        db2.AddObject(tb2);

and save the record.

I hope this will help some one.

Riyasat